# AutoIt's ControlCommand does not pause while a button is grayed out

Tags: while-loop, autoit

This script does not pause until the button is enabled:

```
While Not ControlCommand('Network config', '','QWidget1', 'IsEnabled', '')
    Sleep(500)
WEnd
```

The button is grayed out initially.

Windows title: Network config
CLassnameNN: QWidget1

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Local $cE = 0

AdlibRegister("enControl", 1000) 

While 1
WEnd  

Func enControl()
    Local $wActive = WinActivate("Network config")
    Local $isActive = WinActive($wActive)
    If $isActive = 0 Then
        ConsoleWrite("Could not make window active")
        Return
    EndIf
    $cE = ControlEnable("Network config", ", "QWidget1")
    If $cE = 0 Then
        ConsoleWrite("Could not enable the control")
    Else
        ConsoleWrite("Succesfully enabled the control")
        Sleep(500)
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

Making sure the window is active and using ControlEnable function should help.

Comment: That does not solve the issue. I have similar problem with Winwait which should be really simple. When a programe open, winwait still looping...